[tkinter][python] Show label text after getting results from function
I'm trying to get a label text to show results of a function at button press.
I have funtion which opens a TopLevel window on that window i put 'user name' and press the button to get results from another function and i want to desplay it on a label on the window.
The 'get_aduser_stat_ps' function runs a PS command. At this point i'm only able to print the results on the terminal from the 'get_aduser_stat_ps' function.
How do i return the results to the 'ad_onprem' funtion and desplay it on the label?
Here is the code:
def ad_onprem():

    root = Toplevel()
    root.title('Active Directory On Prem Tool')
    root.geometry('600x400+170+170')
    cb_options = ['Get user statistics', 'Get user Groups']
    user_name = ttkb.StringVar()
    username_en = ttkb.Entry(root, textvariable=user_name, width=30)
    username_en.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: username_en.delete(0, tk.END))
    username_en.place(x=20, y=20)
    username_en.insert(0, 'Please enter user name')
    ad_oprem_cb = ttkb.Combobox(root, values=cb_options, style='primary', width=30)
    ad_oprem_cb.place(x=240, y=20)
    ad_oprem_cb.current(0)
    get_info_btn = ttkb.Button(root, text='Get Info.', width=10, command=lambda: get_aduser_stat_ps(user_name.get()))
    get_info_btn.place(x=450, y=20)
    stat_frame_lbf = ttkb.LabelFrame(root, text='User Statistics', width=460, height=280)
    stat_frame_lbf.place(x=20, y=70)
    ad_user_stat_lb = ttkb.Label(stat_frame_lbf, text=info)
    ad_user_stat_lb.place(x=1, y=1)
    cancel_btn = ttkb.Button(root, text='Exit', width=10, command=root.destroy)
    cancel_btn.place(x=500, y=350)
    root.mainloop()

I have tried global variables but when the code runs the global variable is empty by the time the label code is running which is before the funtion return the results.

If the get_aduser_stat_ps is executed when get_info_btn is clicked, then if you use global variables, then, how they can be empty?? As when you can actually see the button, all the components of root are already initialized.

I think , you should try "return -variable-" command in get_aduser_stat_ps function.

@syildizeli But, I think it would not work here. As, even if value is returned in the get_aduser_stat_ps function, it cannot update the label as asked in the question.

line 27, in ad_onprem
ad_user_stat_lb = ttkb.Label(stat_frame_lbf, text=info)
NameError: name 'info' is not defined

Thanks for the reply Vansh,
The label with the global variable as text runs on the window creation when the global variable is still empty. Only after clicking the button, the 'info' variable receive the correct text.

Thanks for the reply Toyota,
I declared the 'info' variable outside the function. so it will be global. And you are right, I forgot to put it in the code.

OK, I found a workaround solution. I'm also sending the label variable 'ad_user_stat_lb' in the button command, and in the function that gets the info, I have changed the label text with config.
Thanks everyone :-)
